# PetitParser evaluator not working properly

Tags: smalltalk, evaluation, pharo, petitparser

when I try running this code on pharo, my answers are somewhat off. I try evaluating 1-2+3 but for some reason, it does 1- (2+3) and I do not understand why this is so. Thanks for your time.

```
number :=  #digit asParser plus token trim ==> [ :token | token inputValue asNumber ].

term := PPUnresolvedParser new.
prod := PPUnresolvedParser new.
term2 := PPUnresolvedParser new.
prod2 := PPUnresolvedParser new.
prim := PPUnresolvedParser new.

term def: (prod , $+ asParser trim , term ==> [ :nodes | nodes first + nodes last ]) / term2.

term2 def: (prod , $- asParser trim , term ==> [ :nodes | nodes first - nodes last ])/ prod.

prod def: (prim , $* asParser trim , prod ==> [ :nodes | nodes first * nodes last ])/ prim.

prod2 def: (prim , $/ asParser trim , prod ==> [ :nodes | nodes first / nodes last ])/ prim.

prim def: ($( asParser trim , term , $) asParser trim ==> [ :nodes | nodes second ]) / number.

start := term end.

start parse: '1 - 2 + 3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the definition of `term`

```
term
    def: prod , $+ asParser trim , term
        ==> [:nodes | nodes first + nodes last]
        / term2.
```

The `/ term2` part is an `OR` between

```
prod , $+ asParser trim, term ==> [something]
```

and

```
term2
```

Let's mentally parse `'1 - 2 + 3'` according to `term`.

We first read `$1` and have to decide between the two options above. The first one will fail unless `prod` consumes `'1 - 2'`. But this is impossible because

```
prod
    def: prim , $* asParser trim , prod
        ==> [:nodes | nodes first * nodes last]
        / prim.

prim
    def: $( asParser trim , term , $) asParser trim
        ==> [:nodes | nodes second]
        / number
```

and there is no `$*` or `$(` coming, and `'1 - 2'` is not parsed by `#number`.

So, we try with `term2`, which is defined in a similar way

```
term2
    def: prod , $- asParser trim , term
        ==> [:nodes | nodes first - nodes last]
        / prod.
```

so now we have a `OR` between two options.

As above, the first option fails, so we next try `prod`, then `prim` and finally `number`. The `number` parser begins with

```
#digit asParser plus
```

which consumes the digit `$1` and produces the integer `1`.

We are now back in `term2`. We consume `' - '` and are left with `'2 + 3'`; which according to `term` produces `5`. So we get `1 - 5 = -4`.

---

**SHORT EXPLANATION**

For `term` to parse as `(1 - 2) + 3`, `prod` should consume `1 - 2`, which doesn't because `prod` involves no `$-`.